# my sql query to fetch distinct records in descending order of primary key value

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am executing the below query

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS movie_id,video_id,created_date 
FROM video_logs 
WHERE user_id = 2693 AND 
    studio_id=223 AND 
    (DATE_FORMAT(created_date,"%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN "2018-03-16 11:12:12" AND 
    "2018-04-11 20:21:44") 
order by id desc;



+----------+----------+---------------------+
| movie_id | video_id | created_date        |
+----------+----------+---------------------+
|     3751 |     6711 | 2018-04-11 02:19:18 |
|      544 |     2347 | 2018-04-11 14:16:57 |
|      564 |     2367 | 2018-04-11 14:16:08 |
|     1083 |     2998 | 2018-04-11 02:15:21 |
|      544 |     2347 | 2018-04-11 14:14:55 |
|      536 |     2339 | 2018-04-11 14:14:09 |
|     3014 |     5857 | 2018-04-11 01:58:03 |
|     3011 |     5855 | 2018-04-11 13:55:37 |
|     3011 |     5855 | 2018-04-11 13:39:59 |
|     3751 |     6711 | 2018-04-11 01:39:08 |
|     3014 |     5857 | 2018-04-11 01:38:37 |
|     3007 |     5852 | 2018-04-11 13:37:49 |
+----------+----------+---------------------+
```

I wish distinct out put from the above result without hampering the order of movie_id column.

Like My out put should have movie_id column as follows

### movie_id

3751
544
564
1083
536
3014
3011
3007

Thanks In advance for helping me out.

Comment: which value of created_date you want to show for movie_id=544 ?

Comment: Highest value of created_date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by the movie ID. Also, you can use either MIN() or MAX() on the created date to choose which to show when there are multiple rows for a movie_id.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS movie_id,video_id,min(created_date) as created_date
FROM video_logs 
WHERE user_id = 2693 AND 
    studio_id=223 AND 
    DATE_FORMAT(created_date,"%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN "2018-03-16 11:12:12" AND "2018-04-11 20:21:44"
group by movie_id
order by id desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Group your column by then use MAX function to get the latest (highest) datetime value.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS movie_id,video_id,MAX(created_date) as created_date  
FROM video_logs 
WHERE user_id = 2693 AND 
    studio_id=223 AND 
    (DATE_FORMAT(created_date,"%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN "2018-03-16 11:12:12" AND 
    "2018-04-11 20:21:44") 
GROUP BY SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, video_id
order by id desc;
```